# Combing several latex documents into a single document

Tags: combine

I wish to combine three distinct latex documents into a single document. In particular, each document has its own specific directory for images, as well as a distinct bibtex file. Is there a straightforward way to do this?

The solution I have for now is the following:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{doc1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{doc2.pdf}
%... continue for all docs
\end{document}
```

However, the issue here is that the page numbers inherit those of the original document. As such, each new document starts from page 1. Is there a way to in fact number these pages cumulatively?

Comment: Have you tried the `\input` command

Comment: Is the problem with the page numbering only? Or plus wanting to have figures and tables to have unique numbers as well?

Comment: Do these documents use different document classes or conflicting packages?  If not, it should be possible to combine them into a single document using `\input` or `\include`.  Alternatively, perhaps you could rerun them separately with redefined starting page numbers, and combine them after the fact.  The "rerun" `.aux` files should be usable for creating a TOC and similar adjuncts.

Answer (score 1):

The [`com­bine`](https://ctan.org/pkg/combine) class lets you bun­dle in­di­vid­ual doc­u­ments into a sin­gle doc­u­ment, it may be what you are looking for.

Comment: For a valid answer can you please add compilable tex code showing the solution?